# Multiple Selector, put selected options under the input element

Tags: react-select

So, I want to put the selected options in the multi array selector below the select field, and I wonder if there is any smart way to accomplish this than with just using css?

I want something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w85FD.jpg

Reading the docs and I can't really find any prop etc. that'd allow this.

I tried using plain CSS to move them down, but it seems there should be a better way to do it.

Please ignore the selectors for now.

```
.select.below > div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.select.below > div > div:nth-child(2) {

}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with a visual example of what you're trying to accomplish ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, seem like I could not post image yet on this profile. Added a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly recommend you to use Style-in-JS method to do any kind of stylistic customization with `react-select`.

For your specific needs I'll do like this:

```
const styles = {
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }),
  valueContainer: base => ({
    ...base,
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    top: "40px"
  })
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: false
    };
  }
  onChange = options => {
    this.setState({
      values: options
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          onChange={this.onChange}
          isMulti
          options={options}
          styles={this.state.values.length > 0 && styles}
          value={this.state.values}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There's two important parts:

1. The CSS part is replaced by the `styles` props. You can see that there's two places that need update; the `control` container and the `valueContainer`. If you don't update the `justifyContent` property of `control` your icons will end up at the select's left part.
2. The state part where we control the `value` props. Technically it's not really needed but I've added it so we can easily revert the custom `styles` props when the select is empty and have the initial behaviour with the placeholder inside the `Control` component.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/73p0wqppnx).

Comment: Thank you so much, works great! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad to hear @Kerz1! Could you validate the answer please, to indicate other users that the solution is working as expected. Thank you